# Facebook post comment count from Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

In July 2013 Facebook removed the comment count from posts in the graph API. Is there an alternative, currently working way to retrieve the number of comments for a specific post, without having to download all of them? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i don't know your scenario, so can't help you with exact solution. but one way to get comments count is getting it from the [stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream) table using [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql).

there is a structure of comment_info which gives the comment count for any specific post.

see the query below for example:

```
Select type, post_id, description, likes,comment_info from stream WHERE source_id = "*post_id*"
```

put the post id in the clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with the Graph API, by appending `/comments?summary=true` to the request.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10151824665463057%2Fcomments%3Fsummary%3Dtrue

The return object has a summary field all the way at the end (scroll to the bottom to see it in the Graph API explorer). Within the summary there's a `total_count` field.

Answer (score 0):

FQL is deprecated so you should use the Graph API via https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/comments