# facebook graph API endpoint for getting "likes, shares, comments" for post(s)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook is planning to drop support for FQL after V2.0 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog/#v2_0_fql

The below task could be done easily with FQL

```
SELECT like_info.like_count, comment_info.comment_count, share_count 
FROM stream 
WHERE post_id = "POST_ID_HERE"
```

I am unable to find a replacement to the above method in graph api. I know we can get likes and comments count like

```
POST_ID/likes?summary=true AND 
POST_ID/comments?summary=true
```

but I am unable to find a similar endpoint for shares.

NOTE: I am not looking for solutions that take URL input and query graph api for that URL shares, rather I am looking at finding solution to get shares count by POST_ID

```
PAGE_ID/feed?fields=comments.limit(1).summary(true),likes.limit(1).summary(true)
```

I have looked at.

1. [Facebook API: best way to get like, share, comment count for a page/group post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061937/facebook-api-best-way-to-get-like-share-comment-count-for-a-page-group-post)
2. [How to get Likes Count when searching Facebook Graph API with search=xxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755753/how-to-get-likes-count-when-searching-facebook-graph-api-with-search-xxx)
3. [Facebook post comment count from Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494845/facebook-post-comment-count-from-graph-api)
4. http://www.quora.com/Facebook-Graph-API/Facebook-Graph-API-How-to-get-the-number-of-likes-on-a-status

The result should be something like this:

```
{
  "data": [{
      "like_info": {
      "like_count": 3506
    }, 
      "comment_info": {
      "comment_count": 263
    }, 
      "share_count": 278
  }]
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Cheers!

**UPDATE**: It was an access token issue as the token I was using did not have "read_stream" permission.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The field shares does not need the `.summary(true)` at the end. It will bring always the total. But the `likes` and comments does need `.summary(true)`

Example:

`[POST_ID]?fields=shares,likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true)`

**Improved version** works with Graph Api v2.11 (add limit(0) to removes lists of likes and comments and get only summary data):

`[POST_ID]?fields=shares,likes.summary(true).limit(0),comments.summary(true).limit(0)`

This will bring the total count of shares, comments and likes.

You may have a access_token with an `read_stream` permission to get the shares count.

Comment: Yes that is correct, but that is not what I want. I need the share count for post which is not available by the above method.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the rest. I change the answer. Try now.

Comment: If you look closely at the result, you will see there is no shares data. It only has likes and comments data.  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=134039003289754_890855580941422%3Ffields%3Dshares%2Clikes.summary(true)%2Ccomments.summary(true)&version=v2.0

Comment: Strange, for me is coming the shares count, the likes count and the comments count.

Comment: Nice! At the end was just the permission.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54396/discussion-between-jaspal-singh-and-joao-mosmann).

Comment: If anyone comes by here, this still works in November 2015 with Graph API v2.5

Comment: And still working in August 2016 with Graph API v2.7. Thanks!

Comment: @BugHunterUK I just tested here and still works, just had to do a limit change to get only the summary, which is adding a .limit(0) to likes and comments.

Comment: Try this `[POST_ID]?fields=likes.summary(true).limit(0),comments.summary(true).limit(0),shares`

Comment: Shares count is shown only if the post Shares `count > 0`

Answer (score 5):

Get likes, comments and shares and all 3 combined.

Check my ans : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36997725/2439715

**Improved version** *( add limit(0) to removes list of likes and get only summary )*:

```
114916098537132_1265715836790480?fields=shares,likes.limit(0).summary(true),comments.limit(0).summary(true)
```

Comment: `limit(0)` Exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 3):

Get comments, shares, and likes count from post:

`[POST_ID]/?fields=id,shares,likes.limit(0).summary(true),comments.limit(0).summary(true)`

I've included `limit(0)` to prevent the API from spitting out the actual comments and likes. I believe the default limit is `25`.

Please note you can also add these fields to `/feed` to get this data for all the posts on the page.

`[PAGE_ID]/feed?fields=id,shares,likes.limit(0).summary(true),comments.limit(0).summary(true)`

**Final note**: If `shares` data is missing on the return, it is because **the post has no shares**. Instead of returning `"shares": {"count": 0}`, the shares section will be **removed entirely**.

Answer (score 1):

`"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/PAGEid_POSTid/?
fields=shares&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";`

I am using above mentioned endpoint.

Replace `$pageID` and `$videoID` (post id) with your variables.

`"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/" . $pageID."_".$video->id . "/?fields=shares&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";`